# Will this Cooler Master i70 CPU cooler work for Peltier Module TEC12706?

Tags: peltier, cooling

I am trying to make a Peltier cooler using TEC12706 and CPU coolers, the data sheet doesn't mention the cooling capacity of the cooler.

[Cooler Master i70](https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/coolers/standard-cooler/i70/)

[image]

A TEC12706 typically works on 12V and takes 4A i.e. a load of about 50W has to be removed by the cooler.

Will it be able to do the job or I have to move to better alternatives?

Attached: [i70 SpecSheet](https://coolermaster.egnyte.com/dl/QTgr4K6J6E/)

Comment: This can probably be answered if you find the specifications for the heat sink. Too many questions are "I bought this cheap thing without a datasheet, please guess the specifications"

Comment: Hi @pipe, I have attached the link to the specification sheet of the said product for reference. As said in the question, the product sheet does not mention the heat dissipation capacity number wrt fan RPM. I only asked the question if someone has any experience with a similar cooler and its dissipation capabilities. Thanks!

Comment: the general solution to this is: only buy from reputable manufacturers, which provide proper data sheets.

Comment: I assume Cooler Master is a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: The fan has a specification in terms of the airflow it will provide (37CFM +/- 10%), The change in temperature that airflow will cause depends on many other factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed Cooler Master is a reputable manufacture, but you'll need to search further to find the Thermal Design Power (TDP) Specification.

Take a look at this page

[Thermal Design Power (TDP) & CPU Socket Compatibility List - Cooler Master](https://landing.coolermaster.com/pages/tdp-and-socket-compatibility/)

or the pdf provided on that page

[TDP-and-Socket-Compatibility-Table.pdf](https://files.coolermaster.com/pages/tdp-and-socket-compatibility/TDP-and-Socket-Compatibility-Table.pdf)

[image: Cooler Master i70 TDP = 95W]

*Figure 1. List of Cooler Master Products TDP*

It says that Cooler Master i70 TDP = 95W. Since you're not using it as a CPU cooler which the manufacturer intended you to do. There'll probably TDP margin error with your specific peltier module. Also, you would need to actually experiment with it, since the cooling performance depends on ambient temperature, airflow, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks for the on spot answer. I perhaps couldn't reach the table due to my lack of knowledge about a parameter like TDP.

Comment: @Kv07 You haven't known TDP yet? In that case, go google it first or watch video on youtube. For example the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power) or Techquickie's [What is TDP or Thermal Design Power as Fast As Possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDWO177BjZY) video. `The thermal design power, sometimes called thermal design point, is the maximum amount of heat generated by a computer chip or component that the cooling system in a computer is designed to dissipate under any workload.` -- Wikipedia.